# Parent component updates a child component v-for list, the new list is not rendered in the viewport (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My app structure is as follows. The Parent app has an editable form, with a child component list placed at the side. The child component is a list of students in a table.

I'm trying to update a child component list. The child component uses a 'v-for', the list is generated through a web service call using Axios.

In my parent component, I am editing a students name, but the students **new** name is not reflected in the List that I have on screen.

Example:

[image: Parent/Child Component]

Notice on the left the parent form has the updated name now stored in the DB. However, the list (child component) remains unchanged.

I have tried a few things such as using props, ref etc. I am starting to think that my app architecture may be incorrect.

Does anyone know how I might go about solving this issue.

Sections of the code below. You may understand that I am a novice at Vue.

Assistance much appreciated.

```
// Child component
<component>
..
   <tr v-for="student in Students.slice().reverse()" :key="student._id">
..
</component>

export default {
    env: '',
    // list: this.Students,
    props: {
        inputData: Boolean,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            Students: [],
        };
    },
    created() {
    
    // AXIOS web call...
    
    },
};


// Parent component
import List from "./components/students/listTerms";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
    List,
  },
};

// Implementation
 <List />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list component doesn't make a fresh API call each time the form is submitted, the data won't reflect the changes. However, making a separate request each time doesn't make much sense when the component is a child of the form component.

To utilise Vue's reactivity and prevent overhead, it would be best to use props.

As a simplified example:

```js
// Child component
<template>
...
  <tr v-for="student in [...students].reverse()" :key="student._id">
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    students: Array,
  },
};
</script>

// Parent component
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <input v-model="studentData.name" />
      <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </form>
    <List :students="students" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import List from "./components/students/listTerms";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    List,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      students: [],
      studentData: {
        name: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      this.$axios.post('/endpoint', this.studentData).then(() => {
        this.students.push({ ...this.studentData });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/7fy0nqd2/2/)

This ensures data that isn't stored successfully won't be displayed and data that is stored successfully reflects in the child component.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer. My architecture was incorrect. The parent should invoke events to the child and cause reactivity. This was not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is better to use `vuex` for this case and make changes with `mutations`. Because when you change an object in the data array, it is not overwritten. reactivity doesn't work that way read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)